# angular2-data-table server pagination not working

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination

I´m trying to use the angular2-data-table module (https://www.gitbook.com/book/swimlane/angular2-data-table/details) to create my tables. Pagination and Sorting should be handled through the server. To load and set my data from the backend I´m using the following method:

```
this.loadData('sortColumn', 'ASC', this.currentPage, this.options.limit)
  .subscribe(ratings => {
    this.rows = [];
    this.rows.push(...ratings.ratings);
    //For testing
    this.maxRows = 10;
    this.options.count = 10;
    if (this.maxRows < this.options.limit) {
      this.endRow = this.maxRows;
    }
  }, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);}
```

this.rows is the variable I´m binding to the data-table-template:

```
<datatable class="rating_table" [rows]='rows' [options]='options' (onRowClick)='onRowClick($event)' (onPageChange)='onPage($event)'>
```

My problem is when I´m loading the first page the data binding works and in the table my ratings are shown, but when I´m loading the second page this.rows is set to the ratings.ratings object but the table is not refreshing the old ratings are still visible. Can somebody help me I don´t know why the table is not refreshing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some wierd reason angular2-data-table requires that the index in the array match the index of the entire table in the server.  So when you get the data for the 2nd page, the indices in the array should not start from 0 but from [pageSize- 2*pageSize -1]. Essentially you create a sparse array.